# Validate JSON response with JSON Schema in ROBOT Framework

Tags: api, robotframework

I have a JSON response which returns all the details of the users in a company. I have converted those responses to JSON schema and kept it in a file name JSONSchema.json.

Now how do I compare all the responses with the JSON schema ? Can someone please help.

JSON Data

```
[  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Test123",
    "Status": "Active"
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "123Test",
    "Status": "Active"
    }
    ]
```

JSON Schema

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "Id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "Name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Status": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "Id",
        "Name",
        "Status"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "Id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "Name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Status": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "Id",
        "Name",
        "Status"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Code

```
*** Settings ***
Library           jsonschema

*** Test Cases ***
${get_value}=  GET On Session  xyz  /details  

${json_response}=     set variable    ${get_value.json()}

${schema}    Get Binary File    ./myschema.json

${schema}    evaluate    json.loads('''${schema}''')    json

${instance}    evaluate    json.loads('''{"Name":[0,1]}''')    json
 validate    instance=${instance}    schema=${schema}
```

I have issues with the last two lines of the code.

I want the my json response compare to the schema as give a pass message when I get compare the Name : Test123 with the type string in JSON schema

Comment: I have imported the JSONLibrary and then tried load json from file , it gave me the error No keyword with the name load json from file.

Comment: I am new to the JSON schema approach actually, if it was for a single response i could have used should be equal keyboard

Comment: This answer shows how to load JSON: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24734629/how-to-load-a-json-data-file-into-a-variable-in-robot-framework

Comment: @Pekka I have added the code in the question please have a look into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not super familiar with requests library but you could use validate a bit like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library               RequestsLibrary
Library               jsonschema
Suite Setup           Init payloads

*** Test Cases ***
Schematest
    ${response}=        Post     url=http://postman-echo.com/post    json=${payload}
    ${response_json}=   Set Variable  ${response.json()['data']}
    Log To Console      ${response_json}
    Evaluate            jsonschema.validate(instance=${response_json}, schema=${schema})

*** Keywords ***
Init payloads
    ${payload_str}=     Catenate   SEPARATOR=
...        [  {
...            "Id": 2,
...            "Name": "Test123",
...            "Status": "Active"
...          },
...          {
...            "Id": 3,
...            "Name": "123Test",
...            "Status": "Active"
...            }
...            ]
    ${payload}=    Evaluate    json.loads('''${payload_str}''')       json
    Set Suite Variable    ${payload}
    ${schema_str}=     Catenate   SEPARATOR=
...       {
...         "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
...         "type": "array",
...         "items": [
...           {
...             "type": "object",
...             "properties": {
...               "Id": {
...                 "type": "integer"
...               },
...               "Name": {
...                 "type": "string"
...               },
...               "Status": {
...                 "type": "string"
...               }
...             },
...             "required": [
...               "Id",
...               "Name",
...               "Status"
...             ]
...           },
...           {
...             "type": "object",
...             "properties": {
...               "Id": {
...                 "type": "integer"
...               },
...               "Name": {
...                 "type": "string"
...               },
...               "Status": {
...                 "type": "string"
...               }
...             },
...             "required": [
...               "Id",
...               "Name",
...               "Status"
...             ]
...           }
...         ]
...       }
    ${schema}=    Evaluate    json.loads('''${schema_str}''')       json
    Set Suite Variable    ${schema}
```